# Python is running in different version that default one

Tags: python, linux, raspbian

I developed an app with `python:3.8.5` on windows and I want it running on raspberry. But there is `python:3.7.3` and it doesn't work the same as on windows so I tried to install `python:3.8.5`.
When I type `python -V` then it says python 3.8.5 as it should. But when I run `.py` and print version of python then it says `python:3.7.3` because it is running on `python3`.
Check the screenshot here:
https://prnt.sc/1qrs3w1

Picture that `python3 - version 3.7.3` and `python - version 3.8.5`.
How can my `.py` run with `version 3.8.`5 or make transfer the `3.8.5` version to `python3`?

Comment: `python3` is probably a symlink. Recreate it so that it points to the same binary as the `python` one. Use `which python` and `which python3` to find out the symlink locations.

Comment: just run `python script_name.py` or change first row inside script from `#!/some/path/here/python3` to `#!/some/path/here/python`. Use comment above to know what is path of necessary python.